# Почему шифруются и дублируются данные в БД mysql / некорректно вносятся данные в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

В новой таблице все данные ?шифруются?, причём все поля одной строки имеют одинаковое значение.
Есть PHP функции для добавления в таблицу строк:

```
public function saveData(){
        $query = "
                INSERT INTO chat_user_table 
                (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_profile, 
                user_status, user_created_on, user_verification_code)
                VALUES 
                (:user_name, :user_email, :user_password, :user_profile, 
                :user_status, :user_created_on, :user_verification_code)
                ";
        $params = [
            ':user_name'=> $this->user_name,
            ':user_email'=> $this->user_email,
            ':user_password'=> $this->user_password,
            ':user_profile'=> $this->user_profile,
            ':user_status'=> $this->user_status,
            ':user_created_on'=> $this->user_created_on,
            ':user_verification_code'=> $this->user_verification_code
        ];
        $statement = $this->connect->prepare($query);

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindParam($key, $value);
        }

        if($statement->execute())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Исходный код: [Репозиторий GitHub](https://github.com/Flexachiller/websocket-chat)

Все исполняемые файлы: register.php, database/ChatUser.php, database/DatabaseConnection.php

Сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_user_table` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_profile` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_status` enum('Disabled','Enable') NOT NULL,
  `user_created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_verification_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_login_status` enum('Logout','Login') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Не обращайте внимание на то, что user_id без AI.

Comment: Во-первых, в вопросе должен быть [mcve], а не ссылка на репозиторий. Во-вторых, как минимум проверьте содержимое переменной `$params`, чтобы понять, до или после неё портятся данные

Comment: А в репе на гитхабе написано `foreach ($params as $key => &$value) {` Ты уж разберись, где верно. Ну и прочитай заодно что делает `&` перед переменной.